# is it possible to create a Form that will be used by a T4 template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4

I was wondering if it is possible to create a form that will be run on the execution of a t4 template. I would like the values inputted into the form to be used by the template to generate code, similarly to add view in an asp.net mvc project i.e. right click add view and a form would appear to add a new view.

Also in the add view (example discussed above) would it be possible to edit the form that appears i.e. add a new text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar can be done with MVC Scaffolding. Only difference is it uses Powershell as the "UI" and environment. Pretty powerful stuff, you can configure it via command line parameters. Part 5-6-7 contains customization/modification related informations.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

No dialog boxes, and forms aout of the box, but powershell (and any command line) is pretty useful if you are a developer. You can queue up tasks, etc...